# Polycom IP 650 Custom display

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, polycom

I've been googling all over the place and haven't found a good way to do this.  I'm hoping that someone out there has done something like this.

I have Polycom 650's and 331 deployed to my users via a FreePBX (Asterisk) server.  Works like a champ.  What I'm running into are users not having any idea what their extensions or DID's are.  What I'd like to do is put the DID and extension number in the display name and have it scroll on the phone display.  Is that possible?

Running FreePBX with Asterisk 10.

Comment: Are you provisioning the users via XML?  If you are you could put this in the reg.1.label field.

Comment: I need the re.1.label field to be bigger actually.it only shows about 8 characters.

Comment: Is the displayname field too small as well?

Answer (score 1):

With polycom phones, you would normally use the extension (555-5555 for example) as the `reg.1.label` setting in the polycom phone's own config file (path is something like `\polycomtftpDirectory\0a04f23577aa-extension.cfg`).  This places the extension right next to the "line" button on the phone.

This is a setting in the polycom config, not in Asterisk or FreePBX.

```
<polycomConfig>
    <reg reg.1.label="555-5555" />
</polycomConfig>
```

So, `reg.1` is for line 1.  Polycom 430's only have two lines, so you would use `reg.2` for line 2.  If you have a configuration, there are probably other settings there, too.